# Diff, unpivoted

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I want to get the diff of two result sets that are relatively expensive to produce and join. I mention this because I can imagine solutions (using `UNION`, for example) that require joining the sets multiple times. I need it in the following format: `Name sysname, OldValue varchar(max), NewValue varchar(max)`.

Let's say both results sets look like `FirstName varchar(32), LastName varchar(32), Age int, BirthDate datetime`, plus a number of joining columns that won't contribute to the diff result set.

My first thought is something like

```
select
  case when a.FirstName <> b.FirstName then a.FirstName as FirstName_Old,
  case when a.FirstName <> b.FirstName then b.FirstName as FirstName_New,
  /* and so on, for remaining columns */
```

then create two unpivoted result sets, one for the old values, one for the new, then join them. Sounds terrible. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've left off the ELSE and if either (or worse, both) are NULL, the comparison will be false as well.

Apart from those issues, it's probably about as efficient as you are going to get.

If the set of differences is usually small (but the work to get it is large), you could insert only the differences into temporary tables and then work from there with a technique which isn't as visually inelegant (but which requires multiple scans).

Comment: I omitted `ELSE` and null checks for simplicity, but good point nonetheless. Too bad there's not an easier way to do this. In SQL 2008 it seems it could be done with `MERGE` + an `OUTPUT` clause. Does that seems right? Maybe this is a good time to upgrade.